# Loading of Java message properties for internalization

Tags: java, localization, internationalization, translation, properties-file

I have the following Java i18n Message class.:

```
public class Messages { 

    private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "languages.message";
    private static final ResourceBundle RESOURCE_BUNDLE = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE_NAME);

    private Messages() {
    }

    public static String getI18n(String key) {
        try {
            return RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }

    public static String getI18n(String key, Object... params  ) {
        try {
            return MessageFormat.format(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(key), params);
        } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
            return '!' + key + '!';
        }
    }
}
```

I have created the following message properties files.:

```
message.properties
message_de.properties
message_de_DE.properties
```

In my program I get the translation according to the default locale of the system. If it is `de_DE`, the german message properties `message_de_DE.properties` loaded.

If the default locale is `de_CH`, then there is no message properties file. Is then the `message_de.properties` as fallback loaded or do I need to implement it by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://hwellmann.blogspot.nl/2010/02/misconceptions-about-java.html) blog post you are right.

> So when the default locale of your system is de_DE and you request a resource for locale en_US, the lookup order for the properties files is:
>
> 1. MyApp_en_US.properties
> 2. MyApp_en.properties
> 3. MyApp_de_DE.properties
> 4. MyApp_de.properties
> 5. MyApp.properties